# Slow Import of Large MySQL Dump

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a very large MySQL dump file into a new MySQL server.  However, after a certain point, it seems to bog down.   I'm about 250M rows in, and it's taking over 10-12 seconds to run even a single line of the dump.  It seems to hang on "update".

Am I missing something I should do to make this import go faster?  It's a pretty beefy server so I don't think it's the I/O..

Comment: How are you importing this? Maybe you can turn of all foreign key checks for the import to speed it up?

Comment: You've given no details on what you're actually doing.  Are you using LOAD DATA INFILE?  Are you running a bunch of INSERT or UPDATE queries?  If so, what do they look like?  What is the table schema you're updating?

Comment: I'm running it from the MySQL command prompt and piping th efile into that.  It's a bunch of INSERTs.  Very basic table, no foreign keys.

Comment: If it gets progressively worse them you are referencing a non indexed field in your UPDATE

Comment: There are no UPDATEs, just INSERTs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seemed to work for me with a 'beefy' server, was splitting the file into several smaller and importing them all in parallel. Altough that may break your row ordering. (and results may vary depending on storage engine)

IIRC there was some kind of script to do that, but it was unmaintained. So when I was messing with that, I used just head/tail and pipes.

If you are inserting into multiple tables and not using foreign keys, i could probably provide you my simple perl script that I use to split one big dump into per table dumps, which can in turn be imported in parallel.

Also [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys%5d) may help. Either done manually (insert disable at the beginning and enable at the end of your dump file) or when dumping the db. This should speed up your inserts, but it will take quite some time to build indexes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that your data is correct, try disabling foreign checks so the process can be speed up:

```
SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint; do I have to do that at the start of the query or is it something I can do while it's in process?  In other words, would it take effect on the next line?

Comment: Yes, it will take effect after you execute it

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't seem to help.