# how to FAST import a giant sql script for mysql?

Tags: mysql, bigdata

Currently I have a situation which needs to import a giant sql script into mysql. The sql script content is mainly about **INSERT** operation. But there are so much records over there and the file size is around 80GB.

The machine has 8 cpus, 20GB mem. I have done something like:

```
mysql -h [*host_ip_address*] -u *username* -px xxxxxxx -D *databaseName* < giant.sql
```

But the whole process takes **serveral days** which is quite long.Is any other options to import the sql file into database?

Thanks so much.

Comment: At this stage I think the problem is your internet connection, not the way you've approached the problem. 80GB is quite significant.

Comment: what project are you running?

Comment: @utility Some human genome data. You know, they are huge thing. :)

Comment: @Marty Actually, both machines are within the same LAN. The internet is quite fast as far as I can see. I was thinking is there anything wrong with my method. i.e. is mysql will cache the whole giant.sql?

Comment: Interesting - could be. I'll keep an eye on this thread to find out :-)

Comment: Days for this amount of data suggests you are doing a lot of random writes.  An old trick that often helps.  Drop all indexes.  Import data.  Recreate indexes.

Comment: @btilly I will have a try and post the timing results. Thx

Comment: If you are using InnoDB engin, wrap your insert loop into `BEGIN;` `COMMIT;` block and try.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863024/slow-import-of-large-mysql-dump/8424366#8424366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html). It is extremely fast. I've not used it for loading to remote server, but there is [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html) utility. See a comparison of different approaches: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html.

Also you need to convert your sql script to format suitable for `LOAD DATA INFILE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the sql file into several files (on basis of tables) by using shell script & then prepare a shell script to one by one to import the file. This would speedy insert instead of one go.

The reason is that inserted records occupied space in memory for a single process and not remove. You can see when you are importing script after 5 hours the query execution speed would be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your guys help.

I have taken some of your advices and done some comparison on this, now it is time to post the results. The target single sql script 15GB.

Overall, I tried:

1. importing data as single sql script with index; (Take **Days**, finally I killed it. DONOT TRY THIS YOURSELF, you will be pissed off.)
2. importing data as single sql script without index; (Same as above)
3. importing data as split sql script with index (Take the single sql as an example, I split the big file into small trunks around 41MB each. Each trunk takes around **2m19.586s**, Total around );
4. importing data as split sql script without index; (Each trunk takes **2m9.326s**.)

(Unfortunately I did not tried the Load Data method for this dataset)

**Conclusion:**

If you do not want to use Load Data method when you have to import a giant sql into mysql. It is better to:

1. Divide into small scripts;
2. Remove the index

You can add the index back after importing. Cheers

Thanks @btilly @Hitesh Mundra

Answer (score 0):

Put the following commands at the head of giant.sql file

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and following at the end

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
COMMIT;
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1;
```